# Get BD data by AJAX and get null in array cause of acents

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Hi im usssing ajax to get array of data of the bd:

```
$.post
(
"lib/php/load_food.php",
{f:Base64.encode("primeros")},
function(data)
{
firsts = data;
},
"json"
);
```

But in the array firsts, the strings who have a character with acent appear that "null".

I was looking for info or help but dont find any clue of what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PHP [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php), to encode your data on the PHP file, and the use [unescape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) and JQUERY [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to decode and present it normally:

*Simple example:*

---

**PHP FILE:**

```
<?php

$arr = array(
  "title" => rawurlencode("thís ís grêãt!")
);

echo $arr;

?>
```

---

**JQUERY:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
  type    : "POST",
  url     : "path_to_my_file.php",
  data    : "&action=example",
  success : function(response) {
    // Parse PHP Array to Javascript Array
    var arr = $.parseJSON(response);

    // Populate the Title
    $("#my_element_id").html(unescape(arr['title'])).text();
  }
});

</script>
```

---

**RESULT:**
thís ís grêãt!

Comment: Its solves man, very thanks, but if i put the $.parseJSON(repsonse) dont get the array, i just make var arr = response and have it!.